# Need Help Identifying Bug in Simple Multithreaded Code

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I was trying to solve the problem given here - https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/.

I wrote the following code to solve the problem but it exceeds the alloted time limit. I am not able to understand why that is the case. Can someone please point out my mistake ? Also, how can I correct the code given below so that it executes faster while using only while loops to act as a mutex ?

```
class FooBar {
private:
    int n;
    int state = 0;
public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        state = 0;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
            while(state == 1);
            printFoo();
            state = 1;
        }
    }

    void bar(function<void()> printBar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
            while(state == 0);
            printBar();
            state = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You're accessing the value `state` from both threads; that creates a race condition and invokes undefined behavior unless you change `state` to be a `std::atomic<int>`, or guard all accesses to it with a mutex (a proper mutex -- naive while-loops don't count), or ensure that neither thread ever changes its value.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, the problem statement given here - https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/ wants its solvers to allow two different threads to access a shared object of class FooBar. I am using the state variable to make sure that the output is always of the form FooBarFooBarFooBar.... Please go through the link given above.

Comment: Again, a plain `int` cannot be reliably used in the way you are trying to use it.  Sharing a read/write variable between threads requires special handling, and unless you indicate to the compiler that you require that special handling (e.g. by declaring the variable to be `std::atomic<int>` rather than just `int`), the compiler will not generate the code necessary to do what you want it to do, and your program will not work correctly (e.g. when thread A sets the value of `state` to 1, thread B might not ever "see" its value change, and instead may loop in `while(state==0);` forever)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I tried changing the data type of state from int to std:atomic<int> while keeping the rest of the code same and the online judge is still saying  - "Time Limit Exceeded". Any more ideas ?

Comment: Do you think there is a possibility of a deadlock causing the code to take an infinite amount of time to run? I am not able to find any deadlock.

Comment: Simple Multithreaded code is an oxymoron.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Please post answers as such

Answer (score 0):

While loops aren't locks. Locks only allow one thread to pass. In your code if state=0 two threads may print foo one after the another. To solve this problem use a mutex and a unique lock.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
            while(state==1);
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(m1);   //Make mutex m1 as a global mutex
            printFoo();
            state = 1;
        }
```

Never read the same variable across threads withouth making it atomic or modifying the variable within a lock. In this example since the value state is changing within a shared mutex you don't need to use atomic.